# How do I convert the .csv/ .txt file to .xls format automatically once after the .csv/ .txt file generated in server using shell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh

Here I have a abc.csv/abc.txt file( which is will generate automatically) I want to convert that file once immediate after it create to abc.xls and want to attach that abc.xls file to mail automatically from the server(which is in LINUX/UNIX) using shell scripting.

Comment: Excel can read a csv file. Add `SEP=;` as the first line when you want `;` as a sep. Do not try to write excel (with version,.) when you do not need it. 
Men you really want some excel magic, write some makro in excel and schedule that on the client for new files.

Comment: maybe this can help:[link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158254/convert-csv-to-xls-file-on-linux)